# Is it possible to get legalization of Pakistani documents for Finland visa process?

Tags: visas, finland

If you are travelling to Finland on work/residence visa with you family as Pakistani, the marriage certificate, and child birth certificates requires legalization from Finland Embassy. Finland do not have an embassy in Pakistan. What is solution for legalization, and is it possible to get this done?

Comment: Isn't there a Finnish consulate in Islamabad?

Comment: No, No Finnish consulate in any city of Pakistan

Comment: Ask on a nearby (other country) Finnish embassy. They probably know better what to do (maybe they come few days every months, for consular things, or they just have an other country embassy which do consular stuff for them.

Answer (score 3):

From [Finland abroad](https://finlandabroad.fi/web/pak/legalisation-of-documents):

> ## Legalisation of Pakistani documents for Finnish authorities
>
> Pakistani documents must be legalised at the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Pakistan. After that they can be sent directly to the competent Finnish authorities, who will decide if they approve the documents or not.

From the [Ministry Of Foreign Affairs in Pakistan Website](http://www.mofa.gov.pk/) (under the *Consular Affairs* section):

> The primary responsibility of the Consular Affairs Directorate inside Pakistan is to fulfill the requirements of legalization of various documents emanating from Pakistan and abroad. In addition, our Missions provide various Consular Services to Overseas Pakistanis and foreigners within their jurisdiction in the following areas:
>
> [...]
>
> 4. Legalization of documents

Details of different office locations are available on [their website](http://www.mofa.gov.pk/) under the *Consular Affairs* section.